# Swift properyWrapper cannot convert value of declared type to value of specified type

Tags: swift, property-wrapper

Here is my property wrapper:

```
@propertyWrapper struct UserDefaultsBacked<Value> {
    let key: String
    let storage: UserDefaults = .standard
    var defaultValue: Value

    var wrappedValue: Value? {
        get {
            let value = storage.value(forKey: key) as? Value
            return value ?? defaultValue
        }
        set { storage.setValue(newValue, forKey: key) }
    }
}
```

And this variable, snapStatus, is supposed to have a boolean value, right?

```
@UserDefaultsBacked(key: "snap-is-enabled", defaultValue: false)
var snapStatus: Bool
```

But compiler throws an error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UserDefaultsBacked' to specified
>   type 'Bool'

[image]

Am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Works fine on Xcode 11.0.

Comment: Version 11.3.1 (11C504)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve declared `wrappedValue` as an optional, e.g. `Value?`. Change it to not be an optional and the error will go away:

```
@propertyWrapper struct UserDefaultsBacked<Value> {
    let key: String
    let storage: UserDefaults = .standard
    var defaultValue: Value

    var wrappedValue: Value {   // not `Value?`
        get {
            let value = storage.value(forKey: key) as? Value
            return value ?? defaultValue
        }
        set { storage.setValue(newValue, forKey: key) }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could keep `wrappedValue` as is, but then you’d have to declare `snapStatus` as an optional:

```
var snapStatus: Bool?
```

I think the elimination of the optionals is the way to go, but I include this for the sake of completeness.

Comment: What a dumdum I am! thanks, It was optional before adding the `defaultValue` and I forgot to remove the `?`.

Comment: So does the fact that the original code compiles on Xcode 11.0 mean that it was actually a compiler bug in Swift 5.1, and got fixed in 5.1.3?

Comment: I don’t know, but I think the compiler error is appropriate. It doesn’t make sense for a non-optional property to have an optional `wrappedValue`.